# Linux - Does it have an hta equivalent?

Tags: linux, hta

Windows has hta files. They are a bit like html files. They include html5 and javascript but they launch as desktop applications which are **fully-trusted**. (They use a file called mshta.exe found in the IE installed components in order to run.)

The great thing is you can port many web pages to desktop applications with just a few extra lines of code.

Info can be found here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms536496%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Do the latest releases of Linux (and possibly apple mac desktops) have an equivalent of hta files?

Answer (score 1):

If you are aiming to deliver HTML content you can take a much more flexible road: use a GUI framework with HTML capabilities like QT.

[here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/examples-webkit.html) there is a simple example about how to use webkit ( a rendering engine for the web ) to embed a fully working web browser in your GUI, and QT works under many desktop and mobile platforms.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use [node webkit](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit) for this purpose.